# (Ember) Get/lookup component in controller

Tags: ember.js, controller, components

In my route.hbs I have several components that have computed properties. In my controller I want to see the state of these computed properties. I can't two-way bind the values since they are computed properties. Is it possible to do get the instance of a component inside of a controller and inspect its values?

I have tried Ember.$(#) but this just returns the dom object.

Comment: You can't do this. This is not how it works. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: what you want contradicts with the way `ember` is designed at the first place. not only you can get components from controller; you cannot get sub-components from within a parent controller. I suspect you have serious design issues; I would highly recommend to review your design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer applies to Ember 1.13 to at least 3.x.

You have a few options for sharing state. I don’t think there’s a way to grab the values from a component in a controller. That would result in very tangled interdependencies.

Some alternate options are:
- declare the computed properties in the controller and pass them down to the components, rather than defining them on the component
- use a Service for tracking the shared state.
- if the computed properties are based on a record, you could add them to the Model itself